# select the following div of the clicked element with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="contacts">
                <h3><a href="#">1st Link</a></h3>

                <div class="contacts-details">
                 <div class="tel" title="telephone">
                     <p>9806648110</p>
                        <p>9806648110</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fax" title="fax">
                     <p>9806648110</p>
                        <p>9806648110</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="email" title="email">
                     <p>sonill_ss@hotmail.com</p>
                        <p>sanilshakya@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="postal" title="postal">
                     <p>uttam chowk-10, pokhara, nepal</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end .contacts-details -->
            </div><!-- end .contacts -->

            <div class="contacts">
               <h3><a href="#">2nd Link</a></h3>

               <div class="contacts-details">
                 <div class="tel" title="telephone">
                     <p>9806648110</p>
                        <p>9806648110</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fax" title="fax">
                     <p>9806648110</p>
                        <p>9806648110</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="email" title="email">
                     <p>sonill_ss@hotmail.com</p>
                        <p>sanilshakya@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="postal" title="postal">
                     <p>uttam chowk-10, pokhara, nepal</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end .contacts-details -->
            </div><!-- end .contacts -->


            <div class="contacts">
                <h3><a href="#">3rd Link</a></h3>

                <div class="contacts-details">
                 <div class="tel" title="telephone">
                     <p>9806648110</p>
                        <p>9806648110</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fax" title="fax">
                     <p>9806648110</p>
                        <p>9806648110</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="email" title="email">
                     <p>sonill_ss@hotmail.com</p>
                        <p>sanilshakya@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="postal" title="postal">
                     <p>uttam chowk-10, pokhara, nepal</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end .contacts-details -->
            </div><!-- end .contacts -->
```

how do i select the following div (".contacts-details") of the h3 when "h3 a" is clicked and then apply slideToggle() to it?

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('h3 a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.contacts-details').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Or next() in which I think is faster in this case

Comment: can u please suggest a way to select the parent div(div.contacts-details) and apply toggleClass() to it? thank u

Comment: i tried " $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected'); " and it didn't work. it applied class to h3 instead of parent div

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().parent()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('h3 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next('.contacts-details').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I feel like `next()` should only be used when you don't care about what is next. If you want your code to work forever then searching for the exact item you want seems like a better idea to me?

Comment: So what's wrong with next('.contacts-details')? I thought you would se my point

Comment: If you write you're html correctly, contacts-details should be the next element.

Comment: Yes and yes, now you are talking. But I wouldn't always rely on the HTML being in an order you assume.

Comment: that was just a typo, I slipped on my keyboard and wrote 'r' instead of 'e'. Works now